# Why does sf::read_sf not accept an INT column?

Tags: r, postgresql, spatial

I use `sf::read_sf` to load a table from my PSQL database.

The query works fine but it does not fetch my id column, which is formatted as INT. It is also the primary key of the table in question.

I solved the problem by adding a copy of the id column in PSQL, which is being fetched as expected. But it feels... weird.

Code:

```
#### LOAD DATA ####
library(sf)
dsn <- paste("PG:dbname='[dbname]' host='[host]' port='5432' user='[user]' password='[password]')

#load spatial data ('type = 0001' sets geometry type = point, '0003' sets polygon)
ausw_input <- read_sf(dsn, 'regr.hvv_ausw2_hst_nonull_nosingle', type = 0001)
```

The relevant colums of the table are:

```
h_id | INT # primary key, not being fetched
h_id_v | VARCHAR # copy of h_id, being fetched correctly
...
[~30 more columns, including lon/lat]
```

Comment: Are there any other INT columns in your data? Does an INT copy of h_id with no key assignment work? Or only if you convert it to VARCHAR?

Comment: Yes, there is another INT column, which is not my primary key. It is being fetched correctly. Seems like there is an issue with the combination INT & PK.
My INT & PK column contains entries of 5-7 digits, such as 10001 or 8006484

Comment: Had a feeling it would be something like that. I agree that it is strange given INT is such a common PK type. Could be your data or a bug. You should post what you found as an answer rather that as an edit in your question. On SO, self-answering is encouraged. You could also contact the package devs to see if this is expected behaviour.

Comment: Thx! I opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/2336).

Answer (score 0):

No valid solution but at least an explanation how to circumvent the issue:

In my data, there is another INT column, which is not my primary key. It is being fetched correctly. Seems like there is an issue with the combination INT & PK.

--> If you have the same problem, just duplicate your PK column to enable `sf::read_sf` to fetch it.